# Multiple DIVs on same row

Tags: html, css

How can I add multiple divs inside 1 div on the same row, they are being displayed on different lines. I'm only using HTML and CSS.

> [Screenshot of how it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ysva.png)

> [Screenshot of what aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWZLf.png)

**HTML (Div is under Buttons comment):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cook Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="Header">
        <div class="HeaderDiv">
            <h1 class="HeaderText"> Welcome To Cook Book!</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--Buttons-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="Home.html" style="width: 20%">Home</a>
            <div class="RecipesDropDown">
                <button class="RecipesButton" style="width: 20%">Recipes</button>
                <div class="DropDown-Content-Recipes">
                    <a href="ApplePie.html">Apple Pie</a>
                    <a href="BananaPie.html">Banana Cream Pie</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="TermsDropDown">
                <button class="TermsButton" style="width: 20%">Cooking Terms</button>
                <div class="DropDown-Content-Terms">
                    <a href="Terms.html">Pie Cooking Terms</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="DietDropDown">
                <button class="DietButton" style="width: 20%">Cooking Diets</button>
                <div class="DropDown-Content-Diet">
                    <a href="HealthyRecipes.html">Practical & Healthy Recipes</a>
                    <div class="WeeklyDropDown">
                        <button class="WeeklyButton" style="width: 20%">Recipes</button>
                        <div class="DropDown-Content-Weekly">
                            <a href="Week1.html">Week 1</a>
                            <a href="Week2.html">Week 2</a>
                            <a href="Week3.html">Week 3</a>
                            <a href="Week4.html">Week 4</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <a href="Contact.html" style="width: 20%">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Middle Text -->
    <div class="MiddleDiv">
        <p class="MiddleText"> <b>Your Favorite Foods, <br> Your Weight Loss Goals, <br> Your Kind Of Diet!</b></p>
        <input type="email" class="EmailText" placeholder="Enter Your Email" size="35">
        <button type="submit" class="EmailButton"> Subscribe </button>
    </div>
    
    <!--Bottom Watermark-->
    <div>
        <div class="BottomDiv">
            <p> Delicious no-frill meals, all custom selected for your specific calorie goal, delivered to your inbox weekly! </p>
        </div>
        <div class="Watermark">
            <p> © Souheil Tawil - 2021 </p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS (Div styles are under the first comment block):**

```
body {
    background-image: url("../Images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.Header{
    background-image: url("../Images/woodbg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.HeaderDiv{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow:
    -2px -2px 0 #000,
    2px -2px 0 #000,
    -2px 2px 0 #000,
    2px 2px 0 #000;
}

.HeaderText{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
}

.Watermark{
    color: #000000; 
    background-color: white; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}

.BottomDiv{
    color: #ADD8E6; 
    background-color: red; 
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: center; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.MiddleDiv{
    text-align: center;
    text-align: left;
}

.MiddleText{
    margin-top: 330px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -2px -2px 0 #000,
    2px -2px 0 #000,
    -2px 2px 0 #000,
    2px 2px 0 #000;
}

.EmailText{
    margin-left: 150px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.EmailButton{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 6px 30px;
}

                                    /* ---------------------------- */
                                    /*   Drop Down Navigation Bar   */
                                    /* ---------------------------- */

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #668e45;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

                                    /* ---------------------------- */
                                    /*   Drop Down Recipes Button   */
                                    /* ---------------------------- */

.RecipesDropDown {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.RecipesDropDown .RecipesButton {
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a:hover, .RecipesDropDown:hover .RecipesButton {
    background-color: #03fc77;
}

.DropDown-Content-Recipes {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #03fc77;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.DropDown-Content-Recipes a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.DropDown-Content-Recipes a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.RecipesDropDown:hover .DropDown-Content-Recipes {
    display: block;
}

                                    /* ---------------------------- */
                                    /*    Drop Down Terms Button    */
                                    /* ---------------------------- */

.TermsDropDown {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.TermsDropDown .TermsButton {
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a:hover, .TermsDropDown:hover .TermsButton {
    background-color: #03fc77;
}

.DropDown-Content-Terms {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #03fc77;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.DropDown-Content-Terms a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.DropDown-Content-Terms a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.TermsDropDown:hover .DropDown-Content-Terms {
    display: block;
}
                                    /* ---------------------------- */
                                    /*    Drop Down Diet Button    */
                                    /* ---------------------------- */

.DietDropDown {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.DietDropDown .DietButton {
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a:hover, .DietDropDown:hover .DietButton {
    background-color: #03fc77;
}

.DropDown-Content-Diet {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #03fc77;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.DropDown-Content-Diet a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.DropDown-Content-Diet a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.DietDropDown:hover .DropDown-Content-Diet {
    display: block;
}
                                    /* ---------------------------- */
                                    /*    Drop Down Diet Button    */
                                    /* ---------------------------- */

.WeeklyDropDown {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.WeeklyDropDown .WeeklyButton {
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a:hover, .WeeklyDropDown:hover .WeeklyButton {
    background-color: #03fc77;
}

.DropDown-Content-Weekly {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #03fc77;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.DropDown-Content-Weekly a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.DropDown-Content-Weekly a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.WeeklyDropDown:hover .DropDown-Content-Weekly {
    display: block;
```

I tried flex and block inline in the .nav but none worked, white border is to show the button size.

Edit: after adding

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #668e45;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

and modifying width from 20% to fit-content the buttons now work, the border is around the button text not around the whole green div tho. If a better work around fits please let me know.

Comment: Give the parent div "display: flex" and for inside div-s give them "display: inline-block".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you want something like this?**

You can achieve this by using **flexbox**, Create a `div`  in flexbox and wrap all the `Div` inside it. and make sure all you use `flex-direction: row;` to create multiple div in a row. and to make it responsive apply `media query` in it.

[Learn media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[Learn Flex box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .wrap {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;


    }

    .dw {
      width: 180px;
      margin-left: 1px;
      height: 30px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-top: 14px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      background-color: #3A800D;

    }

    a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }



    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 180px;
      padding-top: 14px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: #3A800D;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3A800D;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #3A800D;
      border-radius: 30px;
      width: 180px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }



    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       .wrap{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       align-items: center;
       
  }
  .dw{
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .dropbtn , .dropdown{
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
  </style>

  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="dw">
      <a href="">Home</a>

    </div>

    <div class="dw">
      <a href="">Recipes</a>

    </div>

    <div class="dw">
      <a href="">Cooking Terms</a>

    </div>


    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Cooking Diet
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <hr>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <hr>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="dw">
      <a href="">Contact Us</a>

    </div> -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Let me know if this will help you**.

Use full screen page to preview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your smaller divs CSS:

```
float: left;
```

It will align divs in 1 line all left